# A convergent series $\sum r_m$ such that $\sum r_m^q$ diverges for each $q\in (0,1).$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, divergent-series

Let $\sum_{m} r_{m} < \infty$ be a convergent series such that for all $m$, $r_{m}\in (0,1)$. Can I find some rational $q \in (0,1)$ such that $\sum_{m} r_{m}^{q} < \infty$?

If no, is there a counterexample? I.e, a series $\sum_{m} r_{m} < \infty$ such that for all $m$, $r_{m}\in (0,1)$ and such that for all rational $q \in (0,1)$, $\sum_{m} r_{m}^{q} = \infty$?

Comment: How about $$r_m = \frac{1}{\max\{2, m \log^2 m\}}?$$

Comment: @SangchulLee That makes sense. Here $r_{m}^{q} \rightarrow 0$ for all $q>0$. I have a related question: can you make the terms not converge to zero. The full question is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246856/behavior-of-terms-of-a-convergent-series-when-exponentiated

Comment: @Quantum If $\sum r_n$ is convergent then $r_n \to 0$ and this implies $r_n^{q} \to 0$ for all $q >0$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy. Yes, that is true. But the actual question is at math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246856/…above. There is also a $n_m$ factor there