# Behavior of terms of a convergent series when exponentiated

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} n_{m} r_{m} < \infty$ be a convergent series such that for all $m$, we have that $r_{m}\in (0,1)$ and $n_m$ is a natural number. Can I find some rational $q \in (0,1)$ such that $n_{m}r_{m}^{q} \rightarrow 0$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$?

If no, is there a counterexample? I.e, a series $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} n_{m} r_{m} < \infty$ such that for all $m$,we have that $r_{m}\in (0,1)$ and $n_m$ is a natural number, such that for all rational $q \in (0,1)$, $n_{m}r_{m}^{q} \rightarrow 0$ does not hold?

Comment: You say that you sum over $m$ but then you say that $m$ is some between $0$ and $1$? Could you claify

Comment: @Olba12 edited!

Comment: Does $n_m$ have to be increasing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $n_m = 2^m$ and $r_m = 2^{-m}/m^2$.